# How to calculate md5 checksum of a firmware?

Tags: md5, microcontroller, stm32

I am working on a microcontroller. I have to check loaded firmware is real firmware. For this reason I have to calculate MD5 checksum of loaded firmware. But there is a problem in this action.
MD5 checksum is get 4 32 bits input and gives 4 32 bits output. How am I calculate the whole firmware' s checksum. When I try to calculate, the output is same size of the real firmware and that wastes too much RAM. Is there any posible way to get one output calculated firmware' s MD5 checksum, that is 4 32 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way: https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32-cryp-lib.html#overview

The hard way: https://github.com/mikeferguson/stm32/blob/master/libraries/lwip/src/netif/ppp/md5.c

Both work